# How to send messages on RingCentral programmatically?

Tags: c#, ringcentral, glip

I'm trying to create a program that sends messages to groups from time to time. If I'm not mistaken, the only API I see that send messages is "[Create Post](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Posts/createGlipPost)" which is the "Team Messaging" section. This API uses Glip permission. The test messages that I was sending is being sent to the developer [Glip-App](https://glip-app.devtest.ringcentral.com/) account, when I logged into the Glip-App account, the page didn't look like the regular [RingCentral](https://app.ringcentral.com/) app. The UI is different. I have a feeling, that I am working on the wrong API.

[image]

[image]

I also have few more questions. My program is only required to send messages, but in order to apply for production, I have to practice other API calls as well, such as Get, Delete, Update etc. I'm not sure why it is like that. Also, I had to practice all the permission given, but the only permission I have given is Glip and it's still in the red.

[image]

Finally, the test messages that I've sent, showing the user's actual name on the Glip App page. Is there a way that I can use an alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The test messages that I was sending is being sent to the developer [Glip-App](https://glip-app.devtest.ringcentral.com/) account, when I logged into the Glip-App account, the page didn't look like the regular [RingCentral](https://app.ringcentral.com/) app.

There are two developer sandbox accounts for RC App now, one for the new App and one for the legacy app. At this point, you should be using the new URL. The legacy URL still exists for testing purposes and will be retired at some point in the future at which time the URL should redirect to the new URL.

- New: https://app.devtest.ringcentral.com/
- Legacy: https://glip-app.devtest.ringcentral.com/

> My program is only required to send messages, but in order to apply for production, I have to practice other API calls as well, such as Get, Delete, Update etc. I'm not sure why it is like that. Also, I had to practice all the permission given, but the only permission I have given is Glip and it's still in the red.

This should not be the case. Please [contact the support team regarding this](https://developers.ringcentral.com/support/create-case).

> Finally, the test messages that I've sent, showing the user's actual name on the Glip App page. Is there a way that I can use an alias?

If you are posting using the credentials of a user, the user's name will show up since the user is being represented, not an app. You can also post into a team using a webhook or chatbot in which case other names will appear.

Comment: Hi Grokify, thank you for your answer. It's really helpful.